# Making unopened boxes un-clickable until larger opened box is closed

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am currently playing about with jQuery Isotope. I love it but it is way above my very very basic jQuery knowledge. So far with help from other people I am slowly getting to my end goal. My question today is to see whether it is possible to make the small boxes un-clickable until the big opened box is closed - please refer http://jsfiddle.net/djsbaker/gPuD9/

My ideal was to have each smaller box opening at the very top and pushing all the smaller ones down. This doesn't look like it is possible as after a user clicks on several boxes the larger box drops down on the second line. A way round this would be to not make the smaller boxes un-clickable once the larger one was opened...at least I hope.

Thanks in advance.

DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(".element").click(function () {
    if ($(".element.large").not(this).length === 0) {
        $(this).toggleClass("large");
    }
}
```

This says if there is an element which has the "large" class already on it (not including the element that was clicked) then do nothing. Otherwise toggle the currently clicked elements "large" class.

Your css would then have styling for the "large" class to make the element larger.